# Empty email field of Firebase Auth User using Facebook Login Integration (Firebase 3.0)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I have successfully deployed tutorial code from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login for integrating Firebase Auth logins with Facebook. The users successfully created in Firebase Auth console.

However, I noticed that the Email field in the user object is empty (—). Strangely, I successfully retrieved the email information directly from provider result objects using GraphRequest using the acquired token.

Based on the documentation I read (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getEmail()), the email field should be populated from login providers.

Some additional strange behaviour:

1. After successful login, the onAuthStateChanged is called twice. The
   value of firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getProviderId() is Firebase
   on both occasion
2. I try to list down the providers from the FirebaseUser object, user.getProviderData(). I got two providers: firebase and facebook.com
3. When I tried to update email using FirebaseUser.updateEmail(event.getEmail()), I got this error: An internal error has occurred. [ EMAIL_EXISTS ]

Is there something I miss or did I do something wrong?

Here's my code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "LOGIN_ACTIVITY";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 777;
    private EventBus eventBus;
    private SweetAlertDialog pDialog;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    private ImageView mPasswordVisibilityView;
    private TextView txtPassword;
    private boolean justEnteredAuthStateChanged = false;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        // Firebase
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                final FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Util.logassert("Auth Provider = " + firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getProviderId()); // this is called twice, values of Provider = Firebase 
                    Util.logassert("total provider = " + user.getProviderData().size()); // output = 2. "Firebase" and "facebook.com"
                    for (int i = 0; i < user.getProviderData().size(); i++) {
                        UserInfo info = user.getProviderData().get(i);
                        Util.logassert(info.getProviderId() + ", email = " + info.getEmail()); // both empty
                        Util.logassert("current provider = " + info.getProviderId() + " - " + info);
                    }

                } else {
                    Util.logassert("onAuthStateChanged user logged out");
                }
                // ...

            }
        };
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

        // Firebase Facebook TapAuth
        // Initialize Facebook Login button

        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Util.logassert("facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                Util.logassert("granted = " + loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions()); // output [email and public_profile]
                Util.logassert("denied = " + loginResult.getRecentlyDeniedPermissions());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Util.logassert("facebook:onCancel");
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Util.logassert("facebook:onError" + error.getMessage());
                // ...
            }
        });

        FancyButton btnFacebook = (FancyButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_facebook_share);
        btnFacebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
                Util.logassert("try facebook login");
            }
        });



        txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
    }



    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Util.logassert("handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                token,
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject object,
                            GraphResponse response) {
                        // Application code
                        Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                        Util.logassert("graph res = " + response.getRawResponse());

                        try {
                            /* successfully output email address from graph request here */
                            FbGraphEvent event = new FbGraphEvent(response.getJSONObject().getString("email"), response.getJSONObject().getString("name"));
                            EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(event);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("MomInvoice", "Error in parsing json fb graph", e);
                        }
                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "email,name");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());

        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Util.logassert("signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());


                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Util.logassert("signInWithCredential failed coz = " + task.getException().getMessage());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed :(",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Util.logassert("masuk onStart LoginActivity");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (mCallbackManager != null) {
            mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Util.logassert("hasilx " + requestCode + " = " + resultCode);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am having the same problem, empty email from facebook login. Google login I will try soon

Comment: I'm not familiar w/ the android SDK, but i was facing a similar problem in the javascript sdk w/ google login. as i understand it, firebase 3.0 no longer includes user details in the initial response to an authentication call. that might be why your subsequent call is returning email. hth.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618332/firebase-3-additional-auth-scope-data

Comment: @Muhammad Rayhan, did you ever fix this? I'm having the same issues. The email is not contained anywhere. Same for twitter but twitter login originally requires an extra step to get email.

Comment: Hi @efeturi, I'm still not able to fix this. For workaround, I fetched the email using Facebook GraphRequest , then store the value in Firebase Database instead of Firebase Auth repository. It's not good solution obviously, but I need to launch my apps soon. Hopefully somebody else could help us on this.

Comment: We can get the email from the Error like,
`error.userInfo.FIRAuthErrorUserInfoEmailKey`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

after reading post in firebase-talk google group here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/gPGNq-IkTLo, I found out the answer. The issue was happened because I'm using "Allow creation of multiple accounts with the same email address" in Firebase Auth sign-in method.

So I change the option into: "Prevent creation of multiple accounts with the same email address" can it's working properly now. It's simple as that. It's true I need more logic to merge accounts having the same email address, but it's okay.

Maybe everyone else having the same issue, can also try this, and hopefully it's solved as well.

Comment: Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42609085/10036857). One line code and it's working without any issue.

Answer (score 14):

**Some Facebook accounts are created using Mobile numbers**, so whenever we request for email address we get an **empty string**.

> In the following image, you can see that the facebook account can either set
>   their **Primary contact** as **email address or Mobile number**. So, if a
>   person has marked mobile number as primary, then their email address
>   can't be retrieved.

In my case, I had **forgot to verify my facebook account**, so initially my email address wasn't even showing in Primary contact. **So, if your not getting email address, then please go over to General settings and see whether primary account is set to email address or not.**

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I found the same issue, where email was set to "--" on firebase auth. I was missing permission to read email, which I fixed by:

```
LoginButton mFacebookSignInButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_sign_in_button);
mFacebookSignInButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
```

I hope this helps somebody in future having same issue.

Comment: I have the same issue, in spite of adding read permissions for "email"

Comment: `.setReadPermissions` is now _depriciated_. Use this instead `mFacebookSignInButton.setPermissions("email", "public_profile");`

Comment: What about for Reactjs or Javascript?

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.

There is something called `providerData` in the FirebaseUser. It consists of two data, one from Firebase and another from your sign-in provider (Google, Facebook etc).

[image: FirebaseUser's object]

I am able to get the email from the second providerData.

Comment: Tihis scenario depends on you code your app to give users option to link accounts.
This is what confused me, I thought I needed to "Allow creation of multiple accounts with the same email address" to be able to link accounts, but you don't

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
Here is my code

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.app.pizzawheel.Common.Globals;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class GetStartedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    AccessToken accessToken;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    ProgressDialog progress;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_getstarted);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        final LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login);
        final ImageButton btnFBLogin = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_fb_login);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");

        if (loginButton != null) {
            loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
                    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                            // App code
                            loginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            btnFBLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                            FBLogin();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // App code
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                            // App code
                        }
            });
        }
        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()!=null) {
            accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
            btnFBLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        btnFBLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FBLogin();
            }
        });

    }

    private void FBLogin(){
        progress = new ProgressDialog(GetStartedActivity.this);
        progress.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.show();

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(GetStartedActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback(){

                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                    progress.hide();
                                    progress.dismiss();
                                    try {
                                        Globals.email_address = object.getString("email");
                                        Globals.first_name = object.getString("first_name");
                                        Globals.last_name = object.getString("last_name");
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(GetStartedActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                            parameters.putString("fields","id,email,first_name,last_name");
                            request.setParameters(parameters);
                            request.executeAsync();
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                        } else {
                            progress.hide();
                            progress.dismiss();
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
//                                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
//                                    Toast.makeText(FacebookLoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
//                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                                    updateUI(null);
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out already, this will happen if you activate the setting "Allow creation of multiple accounts using the same email address" in the Firebase console. However, nobody has mentioned that [the documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9134820?hl=en&ref_topic=6386702&authuser=0) actually explains what's going on:

> If you change the default setting by allowing multiple accounts to have the same email address, these functions will not retrieve profile information; if you need this information, you must retrieve it from the identity provider yourself.

So basically you need to manually go and look in the provider data. For example, in Flutter you would look in `auth.currentUser.providerData`. Other platforms may have different property names or getters for accessing the provider data.

There, you would find something like this

```
[
    UserInfo(
        displayName: John Doe, 
        email: johndoe@example.com, 
        phoneNumber: null, 
        photoURL: https://graph.facebook.com/johndoe/picture, 
        providerId: facebook.com, 
        uid: 01234567890123456
    )
]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Muhammad Rayhan. I also did the same. I used `FirebaseUser.updateEmail()` after I got the email from Fb GraphRequest. It worked without issues.

Comment: Hi @efeturi, unfortunately it's not working for me. I got this error when calling FirebaseUser.updateEmail(): error: An internal error has occurred. [ EMAIL_EXISTS ]

Comment: Firstly, I didn't mean to add an answer. I'm on Stack Exchange Android app and I meant to add a comment. That said, have you checked that the email that you're updating with isn't already among your users? I had a case with Twitter after this where updateEmail wasn't working for a Twitter user. Turns out I used the same email for my Facebook and Twitter.

Comment: In my own case, i discovered that some facebook users registered with just their phone number and the email field is permanently blank and no matter what you do, you will not get an email. @efemoney

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  It was caused by creating the Facebook login without any read permissions, tested the login, all OK - then added the read permissions for email.

Facebook showed the updated permissions dialog, but Firebase didn't grab the new email.

I had to delete the user in Firebase console.  Ran the app again, logged in, and email now shows.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way

```
 _facebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
                "email", "public_profile"));
            _facebookLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(facebookAccessToken.getToken());
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(), (me, response) -> {

                            if (response.getError() != null) {
                                // handle error
                                hideProgress();
                                Logcum.w(" GirisActivity ", "facebookSignIn: Giriş anında hata oluştu", response.getError().getException());
                            } else {

                                user_email = response.getJSONObject().optString("email");
                                facebookSignInCredential(user_email);

                            }
                        });

                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "email");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
                    hideProgress(); // progresi gizle

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
                    hideProgress(); // progresi gizle
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know it this is still the issue today, but I had a similar problem in flutter when setting "Allow creation of multiple accounts with the same email address", my firestore user was returning email null, but I found the email address in the user.providerData

Answer (score 0):

Use add scope in provider.

```
  FacebookAuth(): any {
    const providerFace = new auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    providerFace.addScope('email');
    return this.AuthLogin(providerFace);
  }
```

Make sure that the option "an account by email" is selected in the firebase settings under Authentication-advanced. Otherwise, if already another account with the same e-mail registered, that information will not be filled in this way.

Or use providerData[0].email:

```
this.SetUserData(this.provider == PROVEDOR.google ? result.user : result.user.providerData[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Magnus fix, I was able to get the email address from the Provider Data but only from the second object in the list. I'd advise checking the length of Provider Data and checking each node for email address. I only got this error after updating my Facebook SDK version inside Android Studio.
The following code helped me fetch the email address:

```
 user.getProviderData().get(1).getEmail()
```

Where `user` is of `FirebaseUser` who has just been logged in.