# Firebase 3 - Additional Auth Scope Data

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In the Firebase 3 documentation, they say you can grab additional scope data such as this one:

> Optional: Specify additional OAuth 2.0 scopes that you want to request from the authentication provider. To add a scope, call addScope. For example:
>   `provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');`

Once authenicated, I can't find the data as part of the "user" object. Any idea how to pick that extra data ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Firebase V3 will not return the additional requested data when additional OAuth 2.0 scopes are requested. What you need to do is retrieve the credential returned (signInWithPopup and getRedirectResult provide that) and then using the Google accessToken in the credential call the google api to request the additional data.

Comment: i thought this too, but looking @ the sample in the firebase repo, it looks like they're able to access all the data they want from an auth listener.  attempting to recreate it myself & i get none of the fields they're assigning to variables. do you have any sample code for this? :

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/google-popup.html

Comment: The data they access in the sample code is just the current user and its properties which are always available. You can access those from auth.currentUser.*. You also access provider specific data: auth.currentUser.providerData[indexOfGoogleProviderId].email/displayName,etc. Another user reference is returned in signInWithPopup retrieved via result.user.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this out and using Github as an example, was able to retrieve the user's email address only if the user's email address was set to public on github. Passing the `user:email` scope had not effect when the email address was set to private. e.g.

```
provider = new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('user:email');
```