# Firebase Unity Facebook login does not return/save email

Tags: c#, firebase, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using Firebase to allow the user to login to a Unity game via Facebook. It is working fine, but I cannot get access to the user's email by using this parameter `auth.CurrentUser.Email`. Also, the email is not stored in Firebase Authentication Console. The email can be stored/accessed succussfully when I use other sign-in methods, such as email and google.

Here is my code:

```
    public void SignInFacebook()
    {
        var perms = new List<string>() { "public_profile", "email", "user_friends" };
        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms, AuthCallback);
    }

    private void AuthCallback(ILoginResult result)
    {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            // AccessToken class will have session details
            var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
            // Print current access token's User ID
            Debug.Log(aToken.UserId);
            // Print current access token's granted permissions
            foreach (string perm in aToken.Permissions)
            {
                Debug.Log(perm);
            }

            Credential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.GetCredential(aToken.TokenString);
                auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
                    if (task.IsCanceled)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync was canceled.");
                        return;
                    }
                    if (task.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                        return;
                    }

                    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
                    Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} - {2} - ({1})",
                        newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId, newUser.Email);
                });
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
        }
    }
```

And this is what it looks like in the console ("-" is where the email is supposed to be stored. If I use another sign-in method, such as email or google, the email is stored without any issues)

[image]

Similar questions were asked about this issue and it was suggested that I change the **Account email address setting** in Firebase to **Prevent creation of multiple accounts with the same email address**, but it did not solve the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I found this similar thread as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522582/empty-email-field-of-firebase-auth-user-using-facebook-login-integration-fireba

Have you tried deleting the user and adding them again after changing the Account mail address setting?

Comment: @PatrickMartin Yes. It didn't work.

Comment: @PatrickMartin Actually, at first it didn't work because the account I was using was not verified yet. And even after verification, I got the same issue (didn't have access to the email when signing in). However, I was able to get access to the email when I set the email as the primary contact. So, I guess this is the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your Facebook app is in test mode you must login from your Facebook ID. Go to the settings, scroll down, select **Apps and Websites**, and click on your app. From there, make sure email address require is enabled.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
private void FacebookAuthCallback(ILoginResult result)
{
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
    {
        FB.API("/me?fields=id,name,email", HttpMethod.GET, FacebookGetInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
    }
}

private void FacebookGetInfo(IResult result)
{
    if (result.Error == null)
    {
        if (result.ResultDictionary.ContainsKey("email"))
        {
            string aEmail = result.ResultDictionary["email"].ToString();
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(result.Error);
    }
}
```