# Email is getting empty when tried to login from facebook flutter

Tags: flutter, facebook, dart, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication

**I have the user login in the firebase but the email is getting null**
I saw the Facebook developer panel but can't find anything specific about that.
Here is the screenshot of my firebase.[image]

Also when the user login to the application a notification shows on Facebook.

[image: That's a notification from Facebook]

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/37522582/10711216

Comment: that didn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

For me, this issue was solved by requesting `Advanced Access` to the email permission in the Facebook for Developer's app.

In your Facebook developers profile, select your app and navigate to `App Review -> Permissions and Features -> Click on Request Advanced Access` for `email`

Comment: What is the difference between Standard and Advanced Access?

Comment: @naheliegend
As per [Facebook Developers Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/access-levels/)

, `If your app will only be used by people who have a role on it, the permissions and features your app requires will only need Standard Access. If your app will be used by people who do not have a role on it, the permissions and features that your app requires will need Advanced Access.`

Comment: Thank you! Ist the Development <-> Live mode replaced by the Access control?

Comment: I don't think that's the case. I can still see the Development Mode/Live Mode toggle in the Facebook's App Dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this function for Facebook Login in Flutter.
Check the below code.

The plugin i used is flutter_facebook_auth: ^3.4.0.

```
Future<void> facebookLogin(){

 final result = await FacebookAuth.instance
          .login(permissions: ["email", "public_profile"]);

      if (result.status == LoginStatus.success) {

        final OAuthCredential credential =
            FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.accessToken.token);

        final userObj = await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .signInWithCredential(credential); 

        print("Facebook Data with Credentials -> ${userObj.user.toString()}");
       
         
           final email =  userObj.user.providerData[0].email;
           
           final displayName = userObj.user.providerData[0].displayName;
}
```

}

Otherwise you can share your code.

Comment: The same thing happened email is getting null... but when I log in to the developer account only then I got the email. Is there another way to solve that